# Copy the content of a js prompt box - watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

The website I am testing upon clicking a link provides a JavaScript prompt box containing a url within the text input field.

Is there anyway of copying just the link stored within the text field and storing it within a variable?

example of the JavaScript prompt:

```
window.prompt("here is the link", "www.google.com");
```

What I've tried:

```
browser.alert.text
```

returns the result of - "here is the link"

edit:

Image of the event

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the link from the popup, or from the original page source?

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin The popup due to the link being generated, therefore not being within the page source unfortunately. To give you an idea, there is a jquery event bound which when clicked produces this javascript prompt and the link is generated during this event firing.

Comment: What happens to the value when you confirm the prompt box? If it is stored somewhere on the page, it might be easier to retrieve it there instead. To get the value directly from the prompt, it looks like you would have to go into the Selenium-Webdriver code and likely the drivers.

Comment: @JustinKo I can screen shot if this helps. But an outline is we have a table of entries when you click on one you have a "link to this entry" button, this button creates a prompt box which just provides the user with a prompt containing the url to this entry. After clicking Ok the prompt and its value no longer exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see Alert class returns only text: http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Alert

Comment: I am inclined to agree, however I will keep trying to see if I can find a way.

Comment: gave it a pretty good effort, with the current methods available etc this does not seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do

```
var ret = window.prompt("here is the link", "www.google.com");
```

Comment: @Simon What do you mean by `watir` ?

Comment: Web Application Testing in Ruby